# Convert Edittext to readonly and Make it editable on Button Press

Tags: java, android

i got this nw. Before clicking on the button, my `EditText` is just viewable:

[image]

After button press, it should convert to an editable field:

[image]

I want the `EditText` field line to disappear and become read only and on button click make it editable. But this just fades the line and also the text inside it loses it visual appearance.

Here's my code:

```
et1.setEnabled(false);
et1.setFocusable(true);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        et1.setEnabled(true);
        et1.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Just to remove those lines in `Edittext`, `you can use android:background="null"` and to make cursor invisible, `android:cursorVisible="false"`. and then using that button click, set a background to `EditText` and make the cursor visible again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @Fatima Saif! We'd love to help you, but your question isn't [minimal, verifiable, and complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please consider adding to your question so that we can help you out.

Comment: Use both of them, the `editText` should be invisible by default and on click it will become visible but the `textView` will go invisible.

Comment: Use EditText , use android:focusable="false" , android:editable="false"

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar  thnx for ur reply can you expalin your answer through code ? as am newbie i would realy appreciate your help.

Comment: @AJFarmar My appoligies as am new in this , i would make some mistakes but ill try to improve it .

Comment: Exactly thats what i want @samirk433 can you pls explain it through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML should look like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />


  </LinearLayout>
```

Now, add the following code to your activity class.

```
//init the views.
et1.setVisiblity(GONE);
tv1.setVisiblity(VISIBLE);



 //if the textView is shown, the btn click will hide it and show editText 
 //instead, and same happens for editText
  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(){

  if(et1.getVisiblity() != VISIBLE) {
        et1.setVisbility(VISIBLE);
        tv1.setVisibility(GONE);
   } else {
        et1.setVisbility(GONE);
        tv1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
  }

  } });
```

P.S: This isn't executable code, although, hopefully it will get you the idea.

Comment: You have to make it as edittext by default set android:enabled="false" in xml 
And when button clcked set edittext enabled at runtime by
edittext.setEnabled(true);

Comment: @FatimaSaif Although the way I was telling you is different and two views (`EditText` and `TextView`) are not required but this can also work well.

Comment: thnx @samirk433 i'll try this and let you knw.

Comment: @SatenderKumar  thnx for your help guys i really appreciate it.

Comment: @samirk433 sure n thnx for help but it's still nt working dn knw y ? mayb because fragment layout :/

Comment: @FatimaSaif updated the question with your code snap.